# check if laravel eloquent model wasRecentlyUpdated

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
class Customer{
  public function bills(){
    return $this->hasMany(Bill::class);
  }
}
```

```
class Bill{
  public function bills(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
  }
}
```

I have a `Customer` model which `hasMany` `Bills`.
The `Customer` model has a `due_amount` property, now I need to update the `due_amount` property on the `Customer` model when the `Invoice` was generated with some initial `payment` or when the due was paid.
note: `Customer` can have many `Bill` on a single invoice.

**Actual Problem**
I am trying to update `Customer`'s `balance` on the `created` and `updated` events of the `Bill` model. Multiple bills may be created in a lifecycle. But I don't want it to update more than once in a request lifecycle.

I can achieve my goal with the following code. But it's just a workaround.
How to make this code Laravel like?

note: I cannot use `$this->wasChanged()` as the `Customer` is retrieved from the database for each `Bill`. so `$this->wasChanged()` always returns `false`.

```
// App/Models/Customer

public function updateBalance(Bill $bill): void
{
    // Multiple bills may be created.
    // bill may be updated
    // content of the if makes sure that balance property is updated only once in a lifecycle.
    // if another bill is created it is simple ignored. and only due_amount is updated.
    if (!app()->has($this::class . $this->id)) {
        app()->bind($this::class . $this->id, "$this->due_amount");
        $this->balance = $this->due_amount;
    }
    if ($bill->wasRecentlyCreated) {
        $this->due_amount += $bill->due;
    } else {
        $this->due_amount -= $bill->paid - $bill->getOriginal('paid');
    }
    $this->save();
}
```

Comment: _I am trying to update Customer's due_amount on the created and updated event on Bill model._ Then go ahead and try this.

Comment: @nice_dev I have edited the problem. I guess in the first attempt I missed my actual problem. app()->bind() method is not ment to do this type of work. so I was looking for a different way to solve the probelm.

Comment: Why you are allowing to update the bill?